# wait untill for loop not executed fully in node js

Tags: node.js, loops, async-await

I want to send my response when I executed my for loop but it is sending directly without wait in for loop

I have tried with different way and apply wait in async function but it goes to next

```js
async (request, response) => {
  let imageErr = [],
    succArr = [];
  /** Image processing and send to s3 */

  const OriginalUrl = request.body.images;
  for (const image of OriginalUrl) {
    await createImage.createWebp(image, 'webp', (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        imageErr.push(err);
      } else {
        succArr.push(result);
        console.log(succArr);
      }
    });
    /** webp */
    await createImage.createJpeg(image, 'jpeg', (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        imageErr.push(err);
      } else {
        succArr.push(result);
        console.log(succArr);
      }
    });
  }
  if (succArr === 12) responseUtil.success(response, succArr);
  else responseUtil.error(response, 'Fail');
};
```

I expect send response after the for loop is fully executed

Comment: Your functions seem to be callback based, so the `await` has pretty much no effect. Have a look at [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to make them use promises.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you use the kind of framework that accepts a callback instead of returning a Promise (which is necessary for `await` to work properly). One way is to wrap your call into a Promise. Try something like this:

```
for (const image of OriginalUrl) {
    await new Promise((res, rej) => {
        createImage.createWebp(image, 'webp', (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            imageErr.push(err);
          } else {
            succArr.push(result);
          }
          res();  // <-- Important
        });
    });

    (...)
}
```

You may also utilize `rej` but then you would have to catch it as an exception. Your choice.

*Side note:* `if (succArr === 12)`, did you mean `if (succArr.length === 12)`? Also, I assume this is for debug, because it definitely is not a good idea to hardcode literal `12`.

Comment: sorry this should be succArr.length